# How to use Kotlin's coroutines with collections

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm fairly new to Kotlin and its coroutines module, and I'm trying to do something that seemed pretty simple to me at first.

I have a function (the `getCostlyList()` below) that returns a List after some costly computation. This method is called multiple time sequentially. All these calls are then merged into a Set.

```
    private fun myFun(): Set<Int> {
        return (1..10)
                .flatMap { getCostlyList() }
                .toSet()
    }

    private fun getCostlyList(): List<Int> {
        // omitting costly code here...
        return listOf(...)
    }
```

My goal would be to use coroutines to make these calls to this costly method asynchronously, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can write something like this:

```
private suspend fun myFun(): Set<Int> = coroutineScope {
    (1..10)
        .map { async { getCostlyList() } }
        .awaitAll()
        .flatten()
        .toSet()
}
```